# upgrading hibernate from 5.3.2 to 5.4.10 broke compile

Tags: hibernate

We have some critical platform code since the platform loads hibernate beans for the user when the user is doing an edit on a webpage.  The code goes like so

```
@Override
public <T> boolean isManaged(Class<T> paramTypeToCreate) {
    EntityManager entityManager = Em.get();
    try {
        ManagedType<T> managedType = entityManager.getMetamodel().managedType(paramTypeToCreate);
        EntityTypeImpl<T> entityType = (EntityTypeImpl<T>) managedType;
        if(!entityType.hasSingleIdAttribute()) {
            log.warn("You generally should be using beans with hibernate ids since this is a hibernate class");
            return false; //if no single id attribute, let the default creator create the bean
        }

    } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

We did not want to depend on such low level code, but it was the only way to tell if the class coming in was managed by hibernate or not and then looking for an id attribute so we can load the entity.  Is there a new(hopefully more public api) for giving hibernate a Class (ie. bean.getClass() ) and asking hibernate if he is managing that as a hibernate bean and then asking the has single id attribute.  This is for version 5.4.10 specifically.

We are on version 5.3.2 and trying to upgrade.

To add further detail, we are making sure this code will work which comes after to load the entity by it's id

```
    EntityManager entityManager = Em.get();
    Metamodel metamodel = entityManager.getMetamodel();
    ManagedType<T> managedType = metamodel.managedType(paramTypeToCreate);
    EntityTypeImpl<T> entityType = (EntityTypeImpl<T>) managedType;
    Class<?> idClazz = entityType.getIdType().getJavaType();
    SingularAttribute<? super T, ?> idAttribute = entityType.getId(idClazz);
    String name = idAttribute.getName();
```

thanks,
Dean

Comment: What is the compiler error message on which line of code?

Comment: @Selaron in taking a second look, omg, I didn't realize EntityTypeImpl was moved to a new package. sweet, fixed.   Better yet, I can use IdentifiableType now as well(spi) so I am not depending on implementation anymore!!! rocking!!!